# Weierstrass' M-test in reverse

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Weierstrass' M-test says that the series of functions on some set $X$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$$

if $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},  \exists M_n$, \forall x\in X where $M_n \geq |f_n(x)|$, so the majorant series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ converges, then the original series converges uniformly and absolutely for any $x\in X$.

But is the reverse true?

That is:

If I can prove that for some specific sequence of functions, any sequence of $M_n$ with $M_n\geq |f_n(x)|$, will have a divergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n$.

Does that prove that the original sum is not uniformly convergent? can you give any counterexamples?

Comment: a small side-remark: in the $M$-test, the hypothesis should read "$\dots \exists M_n, \forall x \in X \dots$", not the other way around, as you have written it.

Comment: $|f(x)|\leq M_n$ and $M_n$ divergent proves nothing about $f_n(x)$. Let $f_n(x)=2^{-n}$ for all $x$ and $M_n=n$, then $M_n$ diverges but $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly to $1$. On the other hand if $f_n(x)$ diverges for some specific value of $x$ then $M_n$ must diverge.

Comment: @M.Nestor I'm not sure (at all), but the OP might have wanted to write $M_n\ge |f_n(x)|$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a few typos: yes the order in the hypothesis was wrong, and it should say $M_n>|f(x)|$ has been changed to $M_n>|f_n(x)|$.

Comment: And then there was a typo in the comment, I meant "it should *not* say $M_n>|f(x)|$. *It* has been changed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that will not prove that the original sum is not uniformly convergent. For instance, let $f_n(x)=\frac1n\chi_{[n,n+1)}$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly to $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<1\\1&\text{ if }x\in[1,2)\\\frac12&\text{ if }x\in[2,3)\\\vdots\end{cases}$$But $\sup f_n=\frac1n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ diverges. So, if, for each $n$, $M_n\geqslant\sup f_n$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ diverges too.